# Draw a simple graph where its vertices can be divided into 2 sets where every edge joins a vertex in one set to a vertex in the other

Tags: graph-theory

The question is:

Draw a simple graph with the following properties or explain why they do not exist.
The graph has 6 vertices and 8 edges and its vertices can be divided into two sets in such a way that every edge joins a vertex in one set to a vertex in the other.

I don't understand this question but I tried doing this. Since every vertex needs to join every other vertex (for example, in the scenario with two sets where 1 set has 1 vertex and the other has 5 vertices), does this mean that for this graph to exist, there has to be n(n-1)/2 edges?

Comment: See answer here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem

Comment: Is a _planar_ requirement missing?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel no, this is the entire question given

Comment: @DavidG.Stork in the article, the cottages are not connected to each other. in order to answer my question, i should consider the scenario where the cottages  and the utilities are connected to each other right?

Comment: @meromero25:  No.  Re-read your question as stated:  "in such a way that every edge joins a vertex in one set to a vertex in the other."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork im confused. are you assuming that the vertices are in sets of 3 each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose our two vertex sets have $m$ and $n$ vertices respectively; if every edge links one vertex type to another, there can be at most $mn$ edges, when *every* pair of different-type vertices is connected by an edge.

In this question, $m+n=6$, so $(m,n)$ can be $(1,5),(2,4),(3,3)$, up to reversal of variables. These vertex sets allow for 5, 8 and 9 edges respectively. We reject $(m,n)=(1,5)$ as we need 8 edges. The other two choices lead to the two distinct solutions to the problem (the two vertex sets are marked with white and black circles):
[image]

Comment: thanks! but we should reject (3,3) as well right since it requires at least 9 edges to fulfil the statement "every edge joins a vertex in one set to a vertex in the other"

Comment: also, for the (1,5) and (5,1) sets, can i draw it in such a way where the set with the 5 nodes have edges that join each other too?

Comment: @meromero25 (1) we cannot reject $(3,3)$. There are merely _more_ slots available for edges than we require edges. (2) no, since the edges between the set of five do not fit the problem statement.

Comment: oh, i see. thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

Without planarity requirement, the problem is only asking to have a bipartite graph : you need to be able to split the vertices in two "stable sets", i.e. two sets of vertices with no edges between vertices of the same set. As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)

> a bipartite graph (or bigraph) is a graph whose vertices can be divided into two disjoint and independent sets $U$ and $V$ such that every edge connects a vertex in $U$ to one in $V$

For example :

[image]

The easiest exemple fitting the question would be $K_{2,4}$, the bipartite complete graph on 6 vertices, split in two groups. $U$ has size 4, $V$ has size $2$, and all elements of $U$ are linked to all elements of $V$

[image]